# Java - Regex positive Lookbehind causes an error

Tags: java, regex

Look it may seem like I'm trolling but this is legit the regex that I have:

```
(?=([+]{0,1}(mem|[01N]+)([+\/\-*%]([01N]+|mem))+|[-](mem|[01N]+)([+\-*%]([01N]+|mem))*)|(=[+-]{0,1}(mem|[01N]+)([+\-*%]([01N]+|mem))*)|(bt[+-]{0,1}(mem|[0-9]+)([+\/\-*%]([0-9]+|mem))*)|(dec[+-]{0,1}(mem|[01N]+)([+\-*%]([01N]+|mem))*)|([+]?mem)|(quit))|(?<=([+]{0,1}(mem|[01N]+)([+\/\-*%]([01N]+|mem))+|[-](mem|[01N]+)([+\-*%]([01N]+|mem))*)|(=[+-]{0,1}(mem|[01N]+)([+\-*%]([01N]+|mem))*)|(bt[+-]{0,1}(mem|[0-9]+)([+\/\-*%]([0-9]+|mem))*)|(dec[+-]{0,1}(mem|[01N]+)([+\-*%]([01N]+|mem))*)|([+]?mem)|(quit))
```

It's basically 2 parts: the first part will split at positive Lookahead and the second part at positive Lookbehind.The first part is working perfectly but the Lookbehind part gives an engine error.

Site used for testing: https://regex101.com/

Can you help?

Comment: If you want to use a regex with Java you should test it there. The site you posted seems to only support other regex engines which may have more or less subtle differences. Java issues the following error: `Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length`. - This already provides some hint: the lookbehind could be too large so the Java engine will complain. If you know the maximum length, you could try to provide it in the form `{0,max}` where `max` is the maximum length of the match you expect.

Comment: Check the "Match Information" panel ; it will tell you that "lookbehind assertion is not fixed length - offset: 340", which is indeed a problem with most regex engines.

Comment: Switch to the javascript engine in regex101 to avoid this problem (I'm surprised though, I thought I remembered javascript not allowing variable-width lookbehinds either). Of course the real question is what regex engine your target environment uses and whether the regex will work there, and since Java's doesn't support variable-width regexes you'll have to rewrite your regex

Comment: Btw, your expression looks very complex and is hard to read and understand. You might want to think about whether you really need a regex (other ways might be easier and faster) or whether the regex could be simplified. As an example, do you really need the lookaround? Or could simpler match "between A (instead of the look behind) and B (instead of the look ahead)"  be sufficient?

Comment: Man, please check this resource - https://regex101.com/

Comment: You can't use unlimited quantifiers in Java's lookbehinds. Instead of `+` you can use `{1,1000}`, similarly, you can use `{0,1000}` for `*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this more as a comment than an answer, but it easier to show the diagram.

Java does not support variable look behind, this is why you have an error.

If you use **[debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-8ObQid_0SIg0meR)** you will easily understand the regex and will see that your lookbehind is not fixed length.

[image]